# How can I assign the results of a Rails "render json:" and "render_with" to a variable, for storage in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers

I have some code rendering json as follows...

```
        serialized = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(actions, each_serializer: Api::V1::ActionSerializer)
        render json: { actions: serialized }
```

What I need... is to turn serialized into a string so I can store it in a database record. `serialized.to_s` does not work.

How can I turn this `#<ActiveModel::ArraySerializer:0x007fdfddc332b8>` into a string representation of the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActiveSupport::JSON#encode](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html#method-c-encode) to get the string representation of the JSON.

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(serialized)
```